# How to tell branch given changelist?

Tags: unix, perforce

Sounds like it should be easier than I have found; which is

```
p4 change -so <changenum> | grep Client |sed/awk magic| p4 client -o <userclient> | grep -1 View: | tail -1 | <sed/awk magic for depot path>
```

-Chris

Comment: consider adding sample p4 output and required format for results. Impossible to tell what you want expect for the 282 perforce followers. Good luck.

Comment: To clarify: you have a changelist and you want to know what branch/filespec it belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perforce branches are normally just identified by a location in the directory structure (unless you're using streams).  If you know the convention your company uses, it's pretty easy to spot, e.g.:

`//depot/project/main/src/foo.c`

You can also use the Revision Graph in P4V to see the branching history.